# Error deploying a UWP app to an ARM device when using sqlite-net-pcl

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net, xamarin.uwp

When deploying my xamarin forms app (UWP) to the local machine, it works fine. Anyway, when deploying it to my windows device and choosing ARM build, the following error appears:

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'e_sqlite3.dll'. Source files:
>
> C:\Users***\.nuget\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.v140\1.1.2\runtimes\win10-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll
>
> C:\Users***\.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3.v140\1.1.2\runtimes\win10-arm\native\e_sqlite3.dll

I did everything I could, including uninstalling all nuget packages and re-installing them again, nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Note: I could deploy it to the device prior to adding the sqlite-net-pcl package.

Comment: Make sure you use sqlite-net-pcl from praeclarum author.

Comment: @Tiz I did... thats the one i am using.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy [official code sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo) to your arm device?